# WinRT ISupportIncrementalLoading View with Both Directions

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I've a ItemsControl which shows a list of days with some data.
I want this control so be able to scroll infinitely in two directions.

With ISupportIncrementalLoading I could add more days when the end is reached.

But how can I achieve this when the first element is reached?
Does somebody now a collection class which returns the postion of the currently first displayed item?

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is `IObserveableVector`, per this page on MSDN: [Load, store, and display large sets of data efficiently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994637.aspx)

`IObserveableVector` allows you to access data in a random access order, which would allow you to load data at both ends of the list.

I have not used it, nor have I seen many examples on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On the first look it seems like what i'm searching for.