# Implementing Inc loading in Grid View?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have implemented incremental loading capturing the scrollviewer inside the gridview and then binding its ViewChanged event as written in the below code. What logic should i implement that when scroll reaches end of the page then only it should call the webservice? Currently I am doing the following way:

```
private ScrollViewer _scroll;

this._scroll = GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(grdVw1);
            if (_scroll != null)
                _scroll.ViewChanged += scroll_ViewChanged;

async void scrollSnap_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Call the web service
            if (_scrollSnap.ScrollableWidth - _scrollSnap.HorizontalOffset < 10)
            {
                // Webservice call
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to implement [ISupportIncrementalLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading.aspx) in your data collection object.  If your collection implements this, your `GridView` or `ListView` will automatically make the data load calls when the user scrolls to the end of the page.

There is also [IObserveableVector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436519/winrt-isupportincrementalloading-view-with-both-directions), but I have not used it.